# Calling a function recursively for user input

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, recursion, input

I'm trying to make a rock-paper-scissors game,
and am trying to verify the input.

```
def player1():
    x = (raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s): ")).lower()
    if x == 'r' or x == 'p' or x == 's' or x == 'rock' or x == 'paper' or x == 'scissors':
        return x[0]
    else:
        print "Error - wrong input!"
        player1() #I know I can run a While loop, but I need to run it this way.

print(player1())
```

If I enter the right input on the first try, everything works fine.
But if I enter wrong input on first try, and enter the right input on the second time, I get `None` in the output, instead of the first letter of the RPS options.

What am I missing?

Comment: The comment in the posted code states `#I know I can run a While loop, but I need to run it this way.` Seems like @JMG is required to make a recursive call. As @kirelagin points out, in your `else` you need: `return player1()`

Comment: Hmm (*I missed this!*); But this is not a good use-case for recursion IHMO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to want to loop on input.  What you're doing currently is recursively calling `player1`, and the recursive case doesn't have an explicit return value (hence, `None` is returned).

The way you do this is simple:  while there is invalid input, prompt again. I'm using a modified version of this in the vein of the "while True break" style; it accomplishes the same goal.  We loop indefinitely, and if the condition we want is valid, we return; otherwise, we prompt for input and loop again.

```
def player1():
    while True:
        x = raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s): ").lower()
        if x == 'r' or x == 'p' or x == 's' or x == 'rock' or x == 'paper' or x == 'scissors':
            return x[0]
        else:
            print "Error - wrong input!"
```

As an alternative to that `if` statement, there is a slightly more clean way to express it via the `in` operator.

```
if x in ('r', 'p', 's', 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'):
```

---

As an addendum to your original question (as it says that you have to do it recursively), I must strongly caution you against doing *any* input evaluation through recursion.  Python has a call stack size of around 1,000, which means that you have a very finite (yet reasonably large) amount of tries before the program irrecoverably crashes.

Not just that, but your operation stack will be unnecessarily filled with method calls that behave in a similar fashion to a loop.  For memory's sake in addition to the absolute recursion ceiling, *do not use recursion for this.*

If you **absolutely must**, and again I strongly advise ***against*** doing this, then you simply have to return from your iterative case.

```
def player1():
    x = (raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s): ")).lower()
    if x == 'r' or x == 'p' or x == 's' or x == 'rock' or x == 'paper' or x == 'scissors':
        return x[0]
    else:
        print "Error - wrong input!"
        return player1() #I know I can run a While loop, but I need to run it this way.

print(player1())
```

Comment: Put the first `raw_input` in the whole loop, and remove the redundant second one at the end.

Comment: Good idea.  I've modified the answer.

Comment: I’m afraid you didn’t read the comment in the OP’s code: `#I know I can run a While loop, but I need to run it this way.`

Comment: I read it, and added an addendum.  In all honesty, that is the ***worst*** use of recursion, and an appropriate response should be, "No, don't use recursion."  The first time through I explicitly excluded it, stating that the OP would *want* to loop.

Comment: thanx!  the extra-explanation about the memory helped me a lot!
(I kind of suspected this, but wasn't sure)

Answer (score 4):

An improved version of @Makoto's example:

```
def player1():
    x = raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s): ").lower()
    while True:
        if x in ['r', 'p', 's', 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
            return x[0]
        else:
            print "Error - wrong input!"
            x = raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s): ").lower()
```

This is a little more *concise* than many `or` expressions which gets a bit unwieldy if you have a lot of conditions you want to check!

A little explanation:

> We're checking to see `x` (*our user input*) is in pre-defined list of valid inputs.

An even more generalized version of this which becomes *reusable*:

**Example:** (*reusable, non-recursion:*)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from __future__ import print_function  # For Python 2/3 compat


try:
    input = raw_input  # For Python 2/3 compat
except NameError:
    pass


def prompt(prompt="Enter: ", valid=None):
    s = input(prompt)
    while valid and s not in valid:
        print("Invalid input! Please try again. Valid inputs are {0:s}".format(" ".join(valid)))
        s = input(prompt)
    return s


x = prompt("Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): ", ["r", "p", "s", "rock", "paper", "scissors"])
```

**Demo:**

```
$ python foo.py
Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): a
Invalid input! Please try again. Valid inputs are r p s rock paper scissors
Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): foo
Invalid input! Please try again. Valid inputs are r p s rock paper scissors
Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): r

$ python foo.py
Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): a
Invalid input! Please try again. Valid inputs are r p s rock paper scissors
Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): foo
Invalid input! Please try again. Valid inputs are r p s rock paper scissors
Enter action ([r]ock, [p]aper, [s]cissors): rock
```

*PS*: Sorry I didn't answer your question using recursion. IHMO this is not a good use-case for recursion. *Oh well* :) However; this is pretty easy to change:

**Example:** (*reusable, recursive*)

```
def userprompt(prompt="Enter: ", valid=None):
    s = input(prompt)
    while valid and s not in valid:
        print("Invalid input! Please try again. Valid inputs are {0:s}".format(" ".join(valid)))
        s = userprompt(prompt, valid)
    return s
```

Comment: @Scott "postscript"? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the smiley face implies sarcasm or not.  P.S. is an abbreviation for postscript.

Comment: Haha no sarcasm intended just not sure about the "postscript" reference! Oh well :)

Comment: @James why did you import the     print_function ?

Comment: @JMG For Python 2/3 compatibility. ``print`` (*the statement*) became a function in Python 3+

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` branch your function (the first call to your function, in particular) doesn’t `return` anything. In Python functions that do not `return` anything always return `None` implicitly.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! but for some strange reason, the first time I enter a wrong input, it DOES print out the error message, and returns to the first input line...

Comment: @JMG What do you mean by “returns to the first input line”?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer for completeness sake, as you do ask for a recursive solution. Here is my solution that is closest to yours:

```
def player1():
    x = (raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s): ")).lower()
    if x == 'r' or x == 'p' or x == 's' or x == 'rock' or x == 'paper' or x == 'scissors':
        return x[0]
    else:
        print "Error - wrong input!"
        return player1()
```

As you can see, all you've forgotten is a return statement.  A more readable way might be:

```
def player1():
    playerInput=None
    while playerInput not in ('r', 'p', 's', 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'):
        if playerInput is not None:
            print("Error - wrong input!")
        playerInput = raw_input("please select: Rock(r)/Paper(p)/Scissors(s)").lower()
    return playerInput[0]
```

It would be even cleaner with a do while loop, but python lacks that construct.