# Recursive function in while loop changing variable [python]

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I had a student give me the following code:

```
def addtwo():
 numb=input("enter any number")
 add=int(numb)+2
 print(add)
 inp = input("do you wish to enter again")
 while inp=="yes":
       addtwo()
```

After the first iteration, if the user inputs anything other than 'yes', the body of the while loop doesn't execute, as expected. But if we enter 'yes', it executes (again, as expected) and prompts "enter any number", but in the second iteration, even if the user enters anything other than 'yes' on "do you wish to enter again", the body of the while loop STILL executes. Now I ran the debugger on it, and found out that the value of `inp` just changes to `'yes'` when executing line 5. Before execution of the line, the value of `inp`, according to the debugger is still whatever the user entered. Why is that so?

Now I looked it up here, but couldn't find any explanation, though I found a way to work around it by adding a return before the call to `addtwo()` in the body of the while loop (I found it here: [Calling a function recursively for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160315/calling-a-function-recursively-for-user-input)) but couldn't understand why the value of `inp` just change in the local stack, and how the `return` statement fixes it?

Here's the working code:

```
def addtwo():
     numb=input("enter any number")
     add=int(numb)+2
     print(add)
     inp = input("do you wish to enter again")
     while inp=="yes":
           return addtwo()
```

And, to add to my puzzle, the code just works fine if we use an `if` statement instead of `while`.

Comment: If `inp=="yes"`, then the `while` loop is infinite. Nothing inside the loop changes the value of the local variable `inp`. In the second version, the `return` exits the infinite loop by ending the function.

Comment: You're looking at two different `inp` variables; the one from your recursive call, then when that call finishes, it goes back to your main call, where `inp` was originally `yes`. Since it's still `yes`, it loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply, @khelwood and @Davy M: Byt If the `inp=='yes'` statement makes the `while` loop infinite, how does this code work:  
`'myChoice = 'y'  
while myChoice == 'y':  
    myNumber = input('Please enter your number')  
    print(int(myNumber)+2)  
    myChoice = input('Do you want to add another number [y/n]')`

Comment: @UmairRafique Don't try and put code in a comment. For Python, indentation is essential to the behaviour of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a recursive function works a bit like as if you had copied and pasted the inner function there. There are some differences between copy/paste and true recursion:

- Each function gets its own set of variables
- When you copy and paste a function into itself, the function can only call (a copy of) itself as many times as you pasted, whereas recursion automatically goes aribtrarily deep. (That's the whole point of recursion.)

Despite these differences, if you're struggling to understand a recursive call, copy and paste is a good way to think about it. Let's try it for your function. The following code is equivalent to what you wrote, so long as you don't type "yes" too many times:

```
def addtwo0():
     numb=input("enter any number")
     add=int(numb)+2
     print(add)
     inp = input("do you wish to enter again")
     while inp=="yes":
           return addtwo1()

def addtwo1():
     numb=input("enter any number")
     add=int(numb)+2
     print(add)
     inp = input("do you wish to enter again")
     while inp=="yes":
           return addtwo2()

def addtwo2():
     numb=input("enter any number")
     add=int(numb)+2
     print(add)
     inp = input("do you wish to enter again")
     while inp=="yes":
           raise Exception("tried to recurse too deeply!")
```

Maybe it will be even clearer if we put these inline in one function. We'll have to rename the variables so they don't overwrite each other.

```
def addtwo():
     numb0=input("enter any number")
     add0=int(numb0)+2
     print(add0)
     inp0 = input("do you wish to enter again")
     while inp0=="yes":
         numb1=input("enter any number")
         add1=int(numb1)+2
         print(add1)
         inp1 = input("do you wish to enter again")
         while inp1=="yes":
             numb2=input("enter any number")
             add2=int(numb2)+2
             print(add2)
             inp2 = input("do you wish to enter again")
             while inp2=="yes":
                 raise Exception("tried to recurse too deeply!")
```

You can now see the immediate cause of the problem: setting `inp2` to "yes" doesn't set `inp1` or `imp0` to yes. Or in the original code, setting `inp` to "yes" in a nested call to `addtwo` doesn't set the outer `imp` to yes, because each function has its own set of variables.

You can also now see the root cause of the problem: you don't need multiple loops to do this. Either recursion (with an `if`) OR a `while` loop suffices to enable repeated checking of a condition. By having both, even if you fix the immediate problem, you are making things unnecessarily complicated. In this case, a `while` loop would actually be simplest; put the `input` statement in that and get rid of the recursive call altogether.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so well. Now I just have one more question: The first function (I'll call it root, and the others, branches) seems to stop at the body of the first `while` and calls the branch (right?) and when the `while` body of the branch isn't executed, it returns to the root, but why doesn't it do the same with an `if` block? I got your point about using the `while` loop instead of the recursive call (that's the solution I had given), but I just want to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Never mind, I think I just got it. And thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get that how using if instead of while will work fine here. Because it is also executed first time as true and then recursively call the function, which should also mean that it has created another copy of main function and if that copy return false then still first call function has value already set to Yes. So how are they different?

Comment: @Pradhumn Sharma: If you use `if` instead of `while` (and keep the recursion) then yes you're right, the outer copy of `inp` (which you describe as "first call function ... value") will still be set to `"Yes"`. But that's ok, because the `if` test of the outer function has already run and will never run again, so it no longer matters what value it has (whereas a `while` would loop back around and check it again).

Answer (score 4):

**Summary**

This is because once you have entered yes once, that function will loop forever, regardless of what the next recursive call does.

You can fix your code by changing:

```
while inp == "yes":
    add_two()
```

to

```
if inp == "yes":
    add_two()
```

---

**Walk through**

- add_two is called
- the user enters a number
- they are asked if they wish to continue
- they enter "yes"
- while imp == "yes" will now always be true
- it calls add_two

  - they enter a number
  - they enter "no"
  - the loop doesn't run, so returns back to the first call of add_two
- back into the while loop. it still evaluates to true, so continues calling add_two

---

**The return statement**

By default in python, functions which do not return anything, actually return None. This means you call add_two, and if the user does not enter "yes" when prompted, it will return, which will then force the first call to also return.

Comment: I just remembered to add that the 'if' statement works. But, I'm sorry I'm still not clear. In your walkthrough, if the loop doesn't run, why does it return back to the first call?

Comment: @UmairRafique when you call a function from inside another function, the first function pauses where the call happens, and waits for the second function. the second function runs its code, and when it is finished, it returns back to the first function call, which the continues from just after where it called the second function.

Comment: @UmairRafique so if in the second function call the inp is not "yes", the loop will not run as inp == "yes" will be false. therefore, the function will return back to the first

Comment: @UmairRafique hope that makes sense. Also, if my answer contained the answer to your problem, please accept it so other users with the same question can be helped

Comment: Got it! Thanks a LOT bro!

Comment: @UmairRafique no problem :)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get that how using if instead of while will work fine here. Because it is also executed first time as true and then recursively call the function, which should also mean that it has created another copy of main function and if that copy return false then still first call function has value already set to Yes. So how are they different?