# How am I able to make IF statements more efficient?

Tags: python, performance

I have created a small program that takes user input for 'flight specifications' and outputs details of that flight based on the input. However, it is just a bunch of if statements, I was wondering if there are any useful techniques to reduce the amount of if statements and make the program more efficient.

Code:

```
import time

def main():

    AMS_DESTINATION = "Schiphol, Amsterdam"
    GLA_DESTINATION = "Glasgow, Scotland"
    AMS_PRICE = 150.00
    GLA_PRICE = 80.00

    # User input [LLL 0 00 L L]
    flightSpecification = str(input("Enter Flight Specification: "))
    flightDestination = flightSpecification[0:3]

    bagCount = int(flightSpecification[4])
    baggageCost = float((bagCount - 1) * 20)

    passengerAge = int(flightSpecification[6:8])

    standardMeal = 10.00  
    vegetarianMeal = 12.00
    mealType = str(flightSpecification[9])

    seatClass = str(flightSpecification[11])

    totalFlightCost = 0
    
    if flightDestination.lower() != 'ams' and flightDestination.lower() != 'gla':
        print("Please enter a valid flight specification! [LLL 0 00 L L]")
        time.sleep(2)
        main()

    if flightDestination.lower() == 'ams':
        print(f"Destination: {AMS_DESTINATION}")  
        print(f"Flight cost: £{AMS_PRICE}")
        totalFlightCost = 150

    elif flightDestination.lower() == 'gla':
        print(f"Destination: {GLA_DESTINATION}")
        print(f"Flight cost: £{GLA_PRICE}")
        totalFlightCost = 80

    print(f"Number of bags: {bagCount}")
    print(f"Baggage Cost: £{baggageCost}")

    if passengerAge > 15:
        print("Child: False")
        
    elif passengerAge <= 15:
        print("Child: True")
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost / 2
        standardMeal = standardMeal - 2.50
        vegetarianMeal = vegetarianMeal - 2.50
        
    elif passengerAge < 0:
        print("Age cannot be negative")
        main()

    if mealType == 'S' and seatClass != 'F':
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + standardMeal
        print("Meal: Standard")
        print(f"Meal Cost: £{standardMeal}")
        
    elif mealType == 'V' and seatClass != 'F':
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + vegetarianMeal
        print("Meal: Vegetarian")
        print(f"Meal Cost: £{vegetarianMeal}")

    elif mealType == 'N':
        print("Meal: None")
        print("Meal Cost: £0")

    # THIS COULD DEFINITELY BE DONE MORE EFFICIENTLY
    if seatClass == 'F':
        if mealType == 'S':
            totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + standardMeal
            print("Meal: Standard")
            print(f"Meal Cost: FREE")
            
        elif mealType == 'V':
            totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + vegetarianMeal
            print("Meal: Vegetarian")
            print(f"Meal Cost: £{vegetarianMeal}")
            
        print("Seating Class: First")
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost * 6

    elif seatClass == 'E':
        print("Seating Class: Economy")

    print(totalFlightCost)
        
        

main()
```

Thanks

Comment: A different issue is that it's considered bad form to loop recursively to correct for bad input. A loop is preferred i.e. [Calling a function recursively for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160315/calling-a-function-recursively-for-user-input).

Comment: It's not bad form, it's simply wrong.

Comment: Apart from the recursive function to parse user input pointed out by @DarrylG, I don't see any problem in those if's to parse the input. If you are willing, maybe you could change the inputs to command line arguments and then use `getopt`.

Comment: @SiHa--since OP is relatively new, I was trying to be kind.:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

Apart from the comments already below your question, I changed a small thing in the section you mentioned could be optimized (I also removed the user input because it slows down the process, you will understand at the end):

```py
import time

def main2():

    AMS_DESTINATION = "Schiphol, Amsterdam"
    GLA_DESTINATION = "Glasgow, Scotland"
    AMS_PRICE = 150.00
    GLA_PRICE = 80.00

    # User input [LLL 0 00 L L]
    # flightSpecification = str(input("Enter Flight Specification: "))
    flightSpecification = 'AMS 1 22 V F'
    flightDestination = flightSpecification[0:3]

    bagCount = int(flightSpecification[4])
    baggageCost = float((bagCount - 1) * 20)

    passengerAge = int(flightSpecification[6:8])

    standardMeal = 10.00  
    vegetarianMeal = 12.00
    mealType = str(flightSpecification[9])

    seatClass = str(flightSpecification[11])

    totalFlightCost = 0
    
    if flightDestination.lower() != 'ams' and flightDestination.lower() != 'gla':
        print("Please enter a valid flight specification! [LLL 0 00 L L]")
        time.sleep(2)
        main()

    if flightDestination.lower() == 'ams':
        print(f"Destination: {AMS_DESTINATION}")  
        print(f"Flight cost: £{AMS_PRICE}")
        totalFlightCost = 150

    elif flightDestination.lower() == 'gla':
        print(f"Destination: {GLA_DESTINATION}")
        print(f"Flight cost: £{GLA_PRICE}")
        totalFlightCost = 80

    print(f"Number of bags: {bagCount}")
    print(f"Baggage Cost: £{baggageCost}")

    if passengerAge > 15:
        print("Child: False")
        
    elif passengerAge <= 15:
        print("Child: True")
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost / 2
        standardMeal = standardMeal - 2.50
        vegetarianMeal = vegetarianMeal - 2.50
        
    elif passengerAge < 0:
        print("Age cannot be negative")
        main()

    if mealType == 'S' and seatClass != 'F':
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + standardMeal
        print("Meal: Standard")
        print(f"Meal Cost: £{standardMeal}")
        
    elif mealType == 'V' and seatClass != 'F':
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + vegetarianMeal
        print("Meal: Vegetarian")
        print(f"Meal Cost: £{vegetarianMeal}")

    elif mealType == 'N':
        print("Meal: None")
        print("Meal Cost: £0")

    # THIS COULD DEFINITELY BE DONE MORE EFFICIENTLY
    if seatClass == 'F' and mealType is 'S':
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + standardMeal
        print("Meal: Standard")
        print(f"Meal Cost: FREE")

        print("Seating Class: First")
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost * 6
            
    elif seatClass is 'F' and mealType == 'V':
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost + vegetarianMeal
        print("Meal: Vegetarian")
        print(f"Meal Cost: £{vegetarianMeal}")
            
        print("Seating Class: First")
        totalFlightCost = totalFlightCost * 6

    elif seatClass == 'E':
        print("Seating Class: Economy")

    print(totalFlightCost)
```

## Testing

Changing the input in your main, you will recognize in my test below, that there is no real performance issue:

```py
start = time.time()
main()
print('main() takes: ')
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
main2()
print('main2() takes:') 
print(time.time() - start)
```

## Results

main() takes:
7.319450378417969e-05 sec

main2() takes:
4.935264587402344e-05 sec

## Mentionable

In the recursion path which you set (mentioned in the comments) you also use time.sleep(2). Inserting Hardcoded sleeps will always affect your performance.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple program its simply not worth considering efficiency. However, going forward, if you were to be validating a batch of data with hundreds of thousands or more items, then efficiency becomes a concern.

Here are some points to consider:

```py
# flightSpecification = str(input("Enter Flight Specification: "))
flightSpecification = input("Enter Flight Specification: ")
```

Note that `input()` always returns a `str`, so the `str()` around it is redundant.

```py
# mealType = str(flightSpecification[9])
mealType = flightSpecification[9]
```

Similarly, since `flightSpecification` is already a `str`, the `str()` is again redundant.

```py
#if flightDestination.lower() == 'ams':
flightDestinationLower = flightDestination.lower()
if flightDestinationLower == 'ams':
```

Since you do similar comparisons, it might be more efficient to perform the `lower()` once, rather than many times.

```py
flightDestinationLower = flightDestination.lower()
if flightDestinationLower == 'ams':
    print(f"Destination: {AMS_DESTINATION}")  
    print(f"Flight cost: £{AMS_PRICE}")
    totalFlightCost = 150

elif flightDestinationLower == 'gla':
    print(f"Destination: {GLA_DESTINATION}")
    print(f"Flight cost: £{GLA_PRICE}")
    totalFlightCost = 80
else:
    print("Please enter a valid flight specification! [LLL 0 00 L L]")
    time.sleep(2)
    #main()
    continue
```

Rearrange the order of the `if`s so that the `else:` has no need to do comparisons. Also never use recursion where you mean to use iteration.